# Odoo on AWS Elastic Beanstalk OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: odoo-10, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm a newbies on Odoo.

Lately I have been deploying Odoo on AWS Elastic Beanstalk via EB cli.

After I do **"eb deploy"** the server show this message:

```
INFO: New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
INFO: Environment update completed successfully.
```

When I go to the site. It shows this:

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

Here is my "**eb logs**":

**/var/log/httpd/error_log:**

```
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331534 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340] mod_wsgi (pid=10846): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/odoo-wsgi.py'.
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331570 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331586 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]   File "/opt/python/current/app/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 186, in application
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331606 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]     return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331614 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]   File "/opt/python/current/app/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 172, in application_unproxied
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331624 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]     result = handler(environ, start_response)
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331630 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]   File "/opt/python/current/app/odoo/http.py", line 1308, in __call__
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331641 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]     return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331646 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]   File "/opt/python/current/app/odoo/http.py", line 1282, in __call__
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331655 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]     return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331660 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 600, in __call__
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331672 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]     return self.app(environ, start_response)
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331678 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]   File "/opt/python/current/app/odoo/http.py", line 1445, in dispatch
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331686 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]     explicit_session = self.setup_session(httprequest)
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331692 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]   File "/opt/python/current/app/odoo/http.py", line 1342, in setup_session
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331700 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]     session_gc(self.session_store)
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331705 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]   File "/opt/python/current/app/odoo/tools/func.py", line 23, in __get__
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331714 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]     value = self.fget(obj)
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331720 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]   File "/opt/python/current/app/odoo/http.py", line 1293, in session_store
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331727 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]     path = odoo.tools.config.session_dir
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331733 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]   File "/opt/python/current/app/odoo/tools/config.py", line 600, in session_dir
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331751 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]     os.makedirs(d, 0700)
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331757 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]   File "/opt/python/run/baselinenv/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331768 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]     makedirs(head, mode)
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331773 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]   File "/opt/python/run/baselinenv/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331780 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340]     mkdir(name, mode)
[Wed Sep 20 01:41:03.331796 2017] [:error] [pid 10846] [remote 127.0.0.1:24340] OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/odoo'
```

**/var/log/eb-activity.log:**

```
     Disabled forced hourly log rotation.
[2017-09-20T01:41:04.743Z] INFO  [10486] - [Application update app-53e273-170920_083852@76/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/logpublish/hooks/config.
[2017-09-20T01:41:04.743Z] INFO  [10486] - [Application update app-53e273-170920_083852@76/AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2017-09-20T01:41:04.743Z] INFO  [10486] - [Application update app-53e273-170920_083852@76] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy succeeded
[2017-09-20T01:42:45.599Z] INFO  [10989] - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-09-20T01:42:45.599Z] INFO  [10989] - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2017-09-20T01:42:45.599Z] INFO  [10989] - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2017-09-20T01:42:45.599Z] INFO  [10989] - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-09-20T01:42:45.599Z] INFO  [10989] - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-09-20T01:42:45.845Z] INFO  [10989] - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity.
[2017-09-20T01:42:45.845Z] INFO  [10989] - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage 0 - Command CMD-TailLogs stage 0 completed
[2017-09-20T01:42:45.845Z] INFO  [10989] - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2017-09-20T01:42:45.845Z] INFO  [10989] - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2017-09-20T01:42:45.845Z] INFO  [10989] - [CMD-TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded
[2017-09-20T01:47:03.218Z] INFO  [11141] - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-09-20T01:47:03.218Z] INFO  [11141] - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2017-09-20T01:47:03.218Z] INFO  [11141] - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2017-09-20T01:47:03.218Z] INFO  [11141] - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-09-20T01:47:03.218Z] INFO  [11141] - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
```

**/var/log/httpd/access_log**:

```
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [20/Sep/2017:01:40:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [20/Sep/2017:01:41:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [20/Sep/2017:01:41:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [20/Sep/2017:01:41:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
```

I would like to know if anyone had the same problem like this before. If so what did you do to resolve the issue? Or anyone has any idea how to deal with this problem?

I am sorry I could not post images because the site require reputation > 10 . :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I suggest you Reinstall Odoo in your AWS Ubuntu 16.04

Follow the link :

```
https://www.getopenerp.com/install-odoo-10-on-ubuntu-16-04/
```

it's good and Perfect installation on odoo

Comment: Hi Jainik Patel, thank you for your response.

I am able to deploy Odoo 10 on Amazon by take advice from your recommendation and this site also: https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/cms/install-odoo-10-on-ubuntu-16-04.
One more thing: My server environment was built on Fedora. I changed to using Ubuntu instead.